# Localization string validation in Express-Validator

Tags: node.js, validation, express

I'm using express-validator version "2.19.1" for validation. I need to validate name in different languages. I'm using isAlpha(), the default is English alphabet.

```
req.checkBody('name', 'Invalid name').isAlpha();
```

Can I change the setting in express-validator, to allow German special letters ä, ö and ü to pass the validation?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[express-validator](https://github.com/ctavan/express-validator/) is actually powered by a package called [validator.](https://www.npmjs.com/package/validator/)

Validator's isAlpha function provides the ability to include a locale:

```
isAlpha(str [, locale])
```

So I think for German you need

```
req.checkBody('name', 'Invalid name').isAlpha(['de-DE']);
```